# How to convert .csv data in R

Tags: r

I found a dataset I would like to use but the data is set up as follows:

```
userid
q1answer\q2answer\q3answer\q4answer\q5answer\q6answer
```

etc.
there are over 30000 users and roughly 70 q's per user.
I need to be able to access the data as a chart with columns and rows, ie.

```
userid  q1    q2   q3   q4
id#.    answ answ answ answ
```

Is it possible to do this?

It is a .csv file that I am accessing with R.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQPqe.png)

Comment: That is not CSV: it has neither commas nor is it uniformly columnar ...

Comment: Where is the `id#` encoded? I see `q1answer` --> `q1` and `answer`, but not `userid`. Can you give a slightly more detailed sample? Perhaps containing two or three unique user ids. Also, are there the same number of answers for each user?

Comment: I added an image with the info on one user, there are 30,000 other entries like this with different values

Comment: Your sample data is misleading, but I think I understand. In the future, make sure what you show is the same as what you have (your sample data does not show any `\t`, for instance).

Comment: To be clear, is that a tab character or the literal character sequence backslash-T?

Comment: sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow to ask a question and I honestly don't quite understand how the data is presented myself.

Comment: I didn't even think about how it could be a tab character, I think that it probably is a tab

Answer (score 1):

Sample data, saved as a `sampledata` file:

```
39886
3   24  4646    3   19
39999
4   25  4647    4   20
```

(Those are tabs, not spaces.)

Code:

```r
contents <- strsplit(readLines("sampledata"), "\\t")
isuserid <- lengths(contents) == 1
dat <- do.call(rbind,
               lapply(split(contents, cumsum(isuserid)), function(oneuser) {
                 cbind(oneuser[[1]], do.call(rbind, oneuser[-1]))
               }) )
dat <- setNames(as.data.frame(dat), c("user", paste0("q", seq_len(ncol(dat) - 1))))
dat
#    user q1 q2   q3 q4 q5
# 1 39886  3 24 4646  3 19
# 2 39999  4 25 4647  4 20
```